# What protocol does Omnipay sagepay use?

Tags: opayo, omnipay

I've been told that Sagepay protocol 2.x is being deprecated and to upgrade to v3

Taken a look at the source code, but it's not obvious which one it uses, could anyone enlighten me on this?

Comment: See this thread here: https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-sagepay/issues/19

Comment: Thanks! Just the answer I was looking for, it does support v3

Comment: No problems, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses protocol v3.0 as of February 2015 (github/packagist theleague/omnipay-sagepay v2.2.0).

SagePay is due to remove their V2.3 protocol API completely in July 2015. Hopefully that won't catch out too many people when it happens.

The v3.0 protocol does not support the simulator mode, and the OmniPay driver reflects that. I hear rumours that support for the simulator may be brought back later 2015. If so, I'll get support added back into the driver as quickly as I can.

Update: just to clarify, there is still a test mode, so you can test against your SagePay test account. It is the *simulator* mode that never made it to the V3.0 protocol. You can still test without that, and it's fine for shops to do so. The simulator was much more useful to gateway interface developers rather than integrators, so users of OmniPay/SagePay should not really miss out.

Comment: Thanks! That's an odd move, switching protocol without a test mode... Must be fun for you 

Comment: There is still a test mode, so you can force different results using specific card, date and CVV values, and that runs against a test account, which is separate to any live accounts. What is missing is the *simulator* mode, which provides an interactive interface to select what results you want. It was useful because you could see the raw data that SagePay was receiving from your site. However, that was only useful for SagePay Server, where the user is redirected to SagePay anyway, and not relevant for SagePay Direct, so you need a non-simulator fallback to test with that anyway.

Comment: good to know... haven't started playing with sage yet so will keep this in mind.